# Getting a list a tags for a specified photo set with Flickr API

Tags: javascript, api, flickr

I'm new to flickr and the flickr API and I use photo sets to organize my photos.
In an application I'm developping, a need to be able to tag photo sets rather than individual photos; or at least retrieving a tag list given a specified photo set. But it seems like there is nothing of that kind in the Flickr API. So, am I missing something in the API, or does a known workaround for this situation exists ? Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the Flickr documentation for [collections](http://www.flickr.com/help/collections/) and [tags](http://www.flickr.com/help/tags/) and the [API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/), only photos can be tagged, not sets or collections.

To get what you want, you could get tags for photos in a given set using [`photosets.getPhotos`](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html) by specifying `tags` in the `extras` string and display the union of those as tags for the entire set. And conversely, use [`photos.addTags`](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.addTags.html) to add a new tag to each photos in a set.